# Refresh Materialized View concurrently locks the view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to refresh a Materialized View concurrently.

I created the view:

```
reate materialized VIEW mv_secondary_id AS
SELECT  id,
        array_to_tsvector(users_secondary_id(data)) as terms
from users;
```

Added a unique index based on id:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mv_secondary_id_unique_idx ON mv_secondary_id (id);
```

And refresh:

```
refresh materialized view concurrently mv_secondary_id;
```

As I understand from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) - concurrent queries on the view will be able to run on the view, but when I try to refresh and run a query - it waits for the refresh to end and only then completes.

I am using Postgres 11 on GCloud.

Any idea why the query waits?

Comment: What is "users_secondary_id"?

Comment: @jjanes Stored procuedure that returns array of values based on the user data. I am transforming the array to tsvector in order to search on it later (on the view)

Comment: Are you sure it is blocking, and not just being slow due to the high load imposed by the refresh?  Might your stored procedure take locks of its own?  I can't reproduce this.  Is the blocked query selecting a single row by the unique key, or something more complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I used a UI that is only able to run one query at a time - `DBeaver 6.1.4 for linux`.

I tried to run the same queries with pgcli and it worked fine.